# How do I recursively calculate this equation and generate a list of iteration?

Tags: matrix, recursion, difference-equations, education

How do I write a recursive equation to compute a list of answers?
I tried NestList, but it didn't work.

```
A = {{.5, -.6}, {.75, 1.1}};
x0 = {2, 0};

Dot[A,x0]
(* {1., 1.5} *)

Dot[A, {1.`, 1.5`}]
(* {-0.4, 2.4} *)

Dot[A, Dot[A, {1.`, 1.5`}]]
(* {-1.64, 2.34} *)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were correct. `NestList` is exactly the function you want to use.

```
NestList[Dot[A, #]&, x0, 5]

(* {{2, 0}, {1., 1.5}, {-0.4, 2.4}, {-1.64, 2.34}, {-2.224, 
   1.344}, {-1.9184, -0.1896}} *)
```

Note that the first argument of `NestList` must be a function.

Comment: @ JHM foolish me that I didn't realize x0 is the one being operated on, thanks.

Comment: How to visualize the change in x0,x1,x2.. with the no. of operations?

Comment: @thils `ListPlot` would work.

Answer (score 10):

Your can use `MatrixPower` for this example:

```
f[n_] := MatrixPower[{{.5, -.6}, {.75, 1.1}}, n].{2, 0}
f /@ Range[0, 5]
```

yields:

```
{{2., 0.}, {1., 1.5}, {-0.4, 2.4}, {-1.64, 2.34}, {-2.224, 
  1.344}, {-1.9184, -0.1896}}
```

Comment: Or `#.x0 & /@ NestList[Dot[A, #] &, A, 5]` to make it a recursion (starts at matrix power 1).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom  thank you. Yes, the best recursive answer was already provided. I was just providing another in-built approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this recursively, very nearly as you wrote it:

```
a[k_] := a[k] = A.a[k - 1];
a[1] = x0;
```

Now you can calculate any desired iterate by asking for a[5] or a[10]. Or calculate a range of values:

```
a[#] & /@ Range[5]
{{2, 0}, {1., 1.5}, {-0.4, 2.4}, {-1.64, 2.34}, {-2.224, 1.344}}
```